# Insert Image into cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using excel 2010 and I would like to create a function that takes an url as argument and inserts an image to the left of it. If the url cell is emtpy than an error can occur.

[image]

These are my test urls:

```
https://img.reuter.de/products/ge/500x500/geberit-aquaclean-mera-comfort-wc-komplettanlage-weiss--ge-146210111_7c.jpg 

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/NorthYorkHouse2.JPG/220px-NorthYorkHouse2.JPG 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/330px-Flower_poster_2.jpg
```

My function looks like the following:

```
Function displayImage(url)
    Dim url_column As Range
    Dim image As Range

      With image.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url.Value)
        .Left = image.Cells(i).Left
        .Top = image.Cells(i).Top
        image.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
      End With
End Function
```

As you can see in the image above I get `#VALUE`. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Typically a function called from a worksheet can only return a value - it cannot update the sheet directly.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: A UDF on the worksheet cannot change anything on the worksheet or workbook except the value of the cell it is in. There are some unrecommended 'black magic' tricks but I've never see anyone put an image into an adjacent cell. If you plan on continuing, Set image  to something, even application caller.

Comment: This question has been asked on SuperUser with a pretty comprehensive answer: https://superuser.com/questions/940861/how-can-i-display-a-url-as-an-image-in-an-excel-cell

Comment: ... and if you care to review that link, notice that all proposed solutions are sub procedures, not function (let alone worksheet functions).

Comment: @Jeeped my intention was to add resources to help answer the question, but it looks like you've got it under control :)

Comment: @girlvsdata Don't get me wrong. That was an excellent link; I just wanted to reinforce the fact that a worksheet UDF was a dead end before the OP wasted anymore time pursuing it.

Comment: @Jeeped All good.

Comment: @girlvsdata nice research - I'll be looking at that...